# Autoscroll/autostick at the bottom of page when expanding div?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am using this plugin: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm

The DIV im using the plugin on is located at the bottom of my page. when I expand the div, it expands but is there anyway to automatically stick to the bottom of the page during the animation?

I have tried for hours and you guys are m
edit: *m hahha you guys are my only hope now.

think like so:
I have a page which is 1024x1024. in that page I have a div which is 100x100px and a hyperlink. 
when I click on hyperlink it uses the plugin to expand the div to 2048px. twice the original frame size. and then the scrollbar to left appears. What I want is that the page sticks at bottom during the animation so that the user doesnt need to scroll down by himself. The link I poster has the code I have used.

Comment: Can you give some more details? An example, screenshot, fiddle, code, something?

Comment: the code and everything else is in that site? I can make a video and post it? I have to solv this problem. really important

Comment: So you want code that automatically scrolls to the bottom of a box with a scrollbar?

Comment: By what he added to the description I think he wants the page to scroll down while the div is expanding, which he would have to calculate the pages height while its expanding and use one of the scrollto plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want code that automatically scrolls to the bottom of a box with a scrollbar, check out <s>jQuery's `.scroll()` method</s> scrollto plugin [here](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html). Thanks @Patrick.

Comment: .scroll is a event firing method, not something that actually scrolls the content.